# How to access Raspberry Pi Camera via Windows Universal App?

Tags: raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-iot-core

I have a RPI 2 with Windows 10 IoT Preview installed on it, and I'm trying to create a Windows Universal App that displays a live feed from the Raspberry Pi camera (specifically the Pi NoIR camera).  Is this possible?

Comment: Googling, mainly. I have pretty limited programming knowledge, so I have trouble even knowing where to start looking.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Windows.Media.Capture` namespace?  The device may not be enabled at this time either...

Comment: any news on the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible yet. There are no Windows drivers available for the camera. This is likely to change at some point, but your only current option is to use a different OS.

Answer (score 2):

Goobering is correct. Drivers for USB WebCam type devices are likely to be available in the next drop of the OS. I'm uncertain about the RPi camera.

Mark Radbourne (MSFT)

Comment: That's a handicap I'd say - not supporting RPi camera.

Comment: Any news on hte pi camera support?

Comment: It's now early 2017, have the RPi camera support landed yet @mark-radbourne ?

Comment: It's now mid 2019, has the RPi camera support landed yet @mark-radbourne